# Design options required: Managing various storage mechanism

Tags: design-patterns

Suppose the required is:
1) There could be multiple storage mechanism such as .csv/txt/xml/database etc.
2) Whatever might be the storage as per #1, the same Data Structure is going to be used to store the values.

What are the various design option/design patterns could be thought of.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking can be compared to a common set (in this case data) and the representation (different file format), This is similar to [Template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern). You can have a look at it.

HTH!